# Evaluation of diagnostic test ($R^2$ vs AUC)

Tags: roc, diagnostic

A sort of a risk evaluation system is offered to us (sort of advertising). The output value is lethality (yes/no). The evaluators are several diagnoses, emergency status, age etc. No detailed description of the procedure, but two parameters: $R^2$ with 0.4 and AUC = 0.9.

Does it make sense that $R^2$ of 0.4 means that 60% the variance remains not explained with the model, while AUC 0.9 implies reasonable efficacy? Are they  compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to ascertain whether these are unbiased estimates, and which $R^2$ measure was used.  Both the $R^2$ and concordance probability you quote are very high for binary $Y$ but if they are not strongly validated using rigorous internal validation (e.g., bootstrap, repeating all analytical steps for each of a few hundred resamples) or external validation, they can be meaningless.  If the $R^2$ is a psuedo $R^2$ then you can't strictly interpret it as variance explained.

The level of $R^2$ is compatible with a $c$-index (AUROC) of 0.9.